# Parcel won't load images in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, gsap, parceljs

I am using the parcel bundler for my website.

I've been trying to use gsap to change the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag. This change happens when the user clicks on a `<button onclick="changeImage()">`. However, the localhost:1234 server doesn't show this change at all. Can parcel change images of my website after build time?

my html snippet:

```
<img class="mercury_image" src="images/mercury.png"/>
<button onclick="changeImage()"> Click here </button>
```

my javascript snippet

```
function changeImage() {
    gsap.timeline()
    .set(".mercury_image", {
       attr: {src: "images/differentImage.png"}
  })
}
```

Comment: Why would you need gsap to change a src attribute?

Comment: It's not that I need to use gsap to change a src attribute, it's that i'm trying to figure out if parcel can load images dynamically after build time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Parcel [docs](https://en.parceljs.org/assets.html):

> Parcel automatically analyzes the dependencies **referenced in these files** and includes them in the output bundle.

Because there aren't any references to these files at compile-time Parcel doesn't know about them. You need to either add a plugin to track all of your images (like [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy)) or explicitly import them like this:

```js
import differentImage from "images/differentImage.png";

function changeImage() {
    gsap.timeline()
    .set(".mercury_image", {
       attr: {src: differentImage}
  })
}
```